# FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I deployed a React app, but I'm receiving the error message:

@firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL. Be sure to include  a Project ID when calling firebase.initializeApp().

How do I fix this issue?

My firebase.js file currently looks like this...

```
import firebase from "firebase";

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
});

const database = firebase.database();
export const auth = firebase.auth();

export default database;
```

My .env.local file looks like this (I redacted full details)

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXmRv4

REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXd99c.firebaseapp.com

REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXproject-fd99c

REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXd99c.appspot.com

REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX706

REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX54da93
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration object (the one you pass to `initializeApp`) is missing a `databaseURL` property.  It's unclear from your question why it's missing or what you may have done to omit it, but that's what you need.  You can get the string value for that property in the Firebase console for your app under "project settings".

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but now I'm getting a "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly." Everything works perfectly in my build, these errors only occur on deployment.

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different problem.  I can't tell you what your config object should be since I can't access your console.  Check the API key and try again.  Better yet, just copy the entire config object out of the console and try it hard coded to see if it works.  Then work backward from there to see what is wrong.

Comment: It all now works when I enter config object hard coded. Based on what you see in my code I provided above, are there any syntax errors to how I'm handling env? (Thank you btw!)

Comment: Impossible to say.  You'll need to do some debugging to see if you have the right values everywhere you expect.